# Rendering Angular page and scraping information?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cheerio

I'm currently using `Node.js`, the `request` module, and `cheerio` to download pages and scrape information off them. Recently ran into an instance where a specific website is using Angular. I'm unable to get certain data because the JavaScript isn't executed when getting the page.

Any ideas on approaches I can take to get the info I need?

Comment: i'm not sure if cheerio runs the JS on the page. Have you looked into phantomjs?

Comment: Their angular dynamic rendering surely uses some kind of API on their end. Can't you simply scrape off that?